# Getting Button location in array by clicking on it

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, button

I have a grid made out of modified buttons named in the code as `GridEl`. Every `GridEl` are inside the array named as `Grid[,]`, i want to get `GridEl`'s location in array by clicking on it, how i can do it?

For example it have to write in the console the row and the column, and that's how it should look in the console: "Row: 2; Column: 5". Of course every button have to write its own location.*

```
void CreateGrid()
{
            GridEl[,] Grid = new GridEl[4, 6];
            int c, r, gcount; // c = Column, r = Row, gcount = GridEls count
            c = 0; r = 0; gcount = 0;

            while ((c < 7)&&(r < 5) && (gcount != 24)) //Loop that creates grid
            {
                if ((c == 6) && (r < 4))
                {
                    r++;
                    c = 0;
                }
                Grid[r, c] = new GridEl();
                Grid[r, c].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 64);
                Grid[r, c].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21 * 3 * c, 21 * 3 * r);
                MainForm.Controls.Add(Grid[r,c]);
                c++;
                gcount++;
            }
        }


    public class GridEl : Button
    {
//here is the code of GridEl
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your GridEl button class definition

```
    public class GridEl : Button
    {
        public int R { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
```

Add this to your `while` loop

```
    Grid[r, c].R = r;
    Grid[r, c].C = c;
    Grid[r, c].Click += OnClick;
```

and finally your `Click` event handler for the button

```
    private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        GridEl thisButton = sender as GridEl;
        Console.WriteLine($"Row: {thisButton.R}; Column: {thisButton.C}");
    }
```

What you are doing here is simply setting the Row and Column values on the grid button itself, so it always know what the value is and is accessible when it needs it.